# update branch without commits

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-commit

Some time ago I created branch from development branch and actually I did nothing with it, just one commit editing comment.

Now I want to start to work with this branch, but I want to update it with commits from development.

Actually I can just drop it and create branch again, but I'm interested what happened if I do merge or rebase with development.

Because this branch practically without commits, I suppose that there is no difference between merge and rebase. Am I right?

And what happened if I do in other direction first: merge development branch with this branch first?

Comment: It seems easiest just to try it out and see what happens. Just make a copy of your repository and have at it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a rebase and a merge, which will manifest (solely) in your commit history graph.

**Rebase:**

If you do a rebase, your commit history will look like you used your main branch to create your development branch and your one development commit today.  (The timestamps will of course tell a different story).  Your commit history will be linear.

All rebase conflict resolutions will be placed in this development commit.

**Merge:**

If you do a merge, git will create a merge commit that combines your main branch and your development branch.  This merge commit will have two parents - the head (or tip) of your main branch and the head (or tip) of your development branch.  Your commit history will not be linear.

All merge conflict resolutions will be placed in this merge commit.

**Direction of merges**

A merge in git does not have direction, unlike most other VCS.  It doesn't matter if you merge the development branch into the master branch or the development branch into the master branch.  The result should be the same.

**Summary:**

Choosing rebase over merge or the other way around is a per-basis choice but it is a choice that has effects.  [This](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) is a good resource for helping you decide.

Comment: okay, if I don't have any commitments in my branch, will be any difference between merge and rebase?

Comment: If you don't have any new commits on your main development branch (i.e. commits that are on your main development branch but not on your new feature branch), then there will be no difference between a merge and rebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a fast-forward merge if you have no new commits on your feature branch:

```
git merge --ff-only development
```

Comment: always do rebase even I don't have commits - the same result as merge

Comment: You are right, I don't know why I thought that wouldn't work. I removed if from my answer.